# How to display the label and span content in one line?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the label and span content in one line. I tried below code but it's not working. also, I set the width to the label.

In the last label, I have more content as compare to above three. How to set in one line because that is displaying below of the label.

Would you help me out in this?

**I need output like this.**

[image]

```css
html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
.my_office_content{padding: 20px;}
.my_office_content label{width: 250px;font-weight: bold;display: inline-block;}
.my_office_border{border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<div class="my_office_content">

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     </span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem LoremLorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>

    <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.</span></p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all, you should stop abusing `label` as a sort of headline(?), or whatever you actually want this to express here - labels are for form elements.

Comment: @CBroe, Than what should I use instated of the label?

Comment: Something that makes sense, semantically. We don’t know what your data actually represents, and with only “lorem ipsum” it is rather impossible to guess.

Comment: @CBroe, I used label because of heading and span for content.

Comment: h1 to h6 are for headings. Labels are for form elements, using them with non-interactive elements that represent pure text content makes little sense.

Comment: This looks almost like tabular data to me. Ever considered using a `<table>`? :)

Comment: Please check my CSS Solution and let me know if that works

Answer (score 0):

You are putting last span in `<p></p>` that's why it's forming block below.

Comment: I added p tag in the last because I have to display the last span below of the above

Answer (score 0):

You can use the white-space property:

```css
.my_office_border{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: white-space: nowrap; will display the all the content in one line. I have more content in the last one

Answer (score 0):

Put the label inside span

```
<span><label>Label content</label>,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float:left` for both `label` and `span`. Then add `width` so that they stay in their width.

```css
html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
.my_office_content{padding: 20px;}
.my_office_content label{font-weight: bold;}
.my_office_border{border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;}
.my_office_border label { float: left; width: 30%; padding-right: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.my_office_border label+span { float:left; width: 70%; }

.my_office_border::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="my_office_content">

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     </span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem LoremLorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.
</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please check my expected output.

Comment: Kindly check the result now. @NarendraVerma. I hope this is what you expected.

Comment: You set width 30% to the label and 70% to the span, till four is ok, but If I add a one more div without adding the label then it will take 100% width.

Comment: But you must maintain the structure like you have shown in your question. If you want any other HTML structure to be maintained then you must write additional css for that.

Comment: Structure is the same, but at the end, I have to add 2 more div and that is without a label.

Comment: For the last two `divs` add another class and then use `margin-left 30%` for the span.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
.my_office_content{padding: 20px;}
.my_office_content label{width: 250px;font-weight: bold;}
.my_office_border{border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; display:table;width:100%}
.my_office_border label{float:left; width:30%;}
.my_office_border span{float:right; width:70%;}
```

```html
<div class="my_office_content">

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,     </span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem Lorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</span>
  </div>

  <div class="my_office_border">
    <label>Lorem LoremLorem</label>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.
</span>
  </div>
  <div class="my_office_border">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat.
</span>
  </div>





</div>
```

Just Change your CSS like this

```
html,body{margin: 0;padding: 0;height: 100%;}
.my_office_content{padding: 20px;}
.my_office_content label{width: 250px;font-weight: bold;}
.my_office_border{border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; display:table;width:100%}
.my_office_border label{float:left; width:30%;}
.my_office_border span{float:right; width:70%;}
```